# How to configure different server depend on window environment in spring 3.0

Tags: spring-mvc

```
<!-- jBoos Configuration ->
<!-- Local -->
mysql configuration
```

I want to enable both not comment any one of configuration. which configuration is setup depend by windows environment like`linux` or `windows`

Comment: Why do you need it? Usually developers try to mimic the production environment on their machines as close as possible, cause even though the Java is cross-platform you'll certainly encounter some differences between application servers at some point

Comment: i need because my loacal server on window which is configure by tomcat & site server on linux which is configure by jboss. so i prevent the  commnet this section.

Comment: any chance of installing the jboss on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, sort of manually:

Keep the configuration outside the application war-files.
The project repository contains sample config-files for different needs.
On your machine, or on the server, simply create (or copy from sample) the needed config file.

In spring, read in the config like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/etc/project-name/config.properties"/>
```

The path /etc/... works on windows also. It points towards c:\etc...